# How do I grant permissions to Xcode？

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I encountered privilege issues when using react-native development.
Creating a new folder when using the react-native-fs plug-in was unsuccessful.
Just in the **IOS**. please help !!!
[image]

Comment: If you need to change permissions of folder/file in iOS you can do the following : Right click on the file, Get Info, and sharing & permission

Comment: I tried, but it's the same thing.

Comment: From the warning, there seems to be some problem no ? folder "null" is probably the wrong folder...

Comment: fixed successful !